# YouTube Live - change LiveStream while broadcast is live

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Not sure if this is something obvious or not. After creating an YouTube LiveBroadcast, binding that to a LiveStream with a specific CDN format (let's say "720p"), and transitioning the broadcast from "ready" to "live" ... how can I change the stream quality without having to create a new broadcast?

Trying to unbind the current stream - exception is returned, cannot unbind the stream.

Trying to bind broadcast to another stream - same exception as above.

In addition, after looking through the support pages for YouTube live streaming, it is suggested that "ingest settings cannot be modified after the broadcast has started" - it says nothing about the actual API not being able to support this, but it looks like a major limitation from somewhere deeper. I only thought it applies to the web Live Control room.

I need this functionality so that I can change the stream quality for when a  user switches from WiFi to mobile data. Currently streaming RTMP data in another resolution that what the LiveStream CDN format is configured for, results in health errors and encoding artifacts on YouTube's side. As suggested by the support pages, creating a "1080p" live stream ("maximum expected resolution") should work, but when that stream is receiving a 720p or 480p stream, depending on whether it was started or not, it either doesn't start at all, or goes to a gray scene with high-pitch audio (my stream is sent correctly, since I can output it to a dozen more outputs, like MP4, FLV, and other RTMP servers).

Solution?

Comment: Have you tried calling the `update` API of a `LiveStream`? It will update the video stream, however, in the event that it does not; the documentation suggests that you create a new stream with proper settings.

Comment: Updating an active stream which is bound to a broadcast that transitioned to live yields an error: "reason": "liveStreamModificationNotAllowed", "message": "Modification is not allowed in current state". It doesn't help me to create a new stream if I can't bind it to an existing broadcast.